# Wowza with react js

Tags: reactjs, wowza

I need to do live streaming in my react js app with wowza, I added wowza player script  inside my html file.Is there any way to do it in my component?

Comment: Check npm if there is any wowza package for React.

Comment: There is no wowza package available for React.js

Comment: https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/51402/wowza-player-with-react.html

Check this out, I think you can use this

Answer (score 2):

Wowza doesn't currently officially offer or support a React Native wrapper, but we have had reports of successful streams using some third-party wrappers on GitHub.

Here are two React wrappers on GitHub you can try:

https://github.com/flextv/react-native-wowza-player

https://github.com/medlmobileenterprises/react-native-wowza-gocoder